# Como mostrar el valor de un input text en un tooltip

Tags: html, jquery, tooltip

**Estimados**

Como se podría pasar el valor de un input text a un tooltip de manera que si el valor del input cambia, el del tooltip tambien?

Aquí dejo el código que tengo .

```
<!DocType:html>
<html>
<head>

<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
<br><br><br>



<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" id="inputDatos" value="DATO"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!"></div>

<script>
$(function () {
var campo = $("inputDatos").val();
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(campo)
})

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Aquí la imagen
Solo me muestra el title en el tooltip, pero
como se puede hacer para que tome el valor del input?
he buscado pero no he encontrado nada en internet.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comentan anteriormente, deberias de detectar algun tipo de evento en el input, en el caso que te dejo, se dispara al realizar un entrada en tu id '#inputDatos'. Aquí tienes algo de documentación acerca del evento https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

También podría funciona con *keypress* o similar. Cada vez que ejecutes el evento, para refrescar el valor del atributo title, levanta el tooltip con el metodo tooltip('show').

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#inputDatos').on('input',function(){

             var entrada = $('#inputDatos').val();
             var campo = $('#inputDatos').attr('data-original-title',entrada);
             $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show');

            });

           $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
           }); 
  });
```

Espero te sirva, un saludo

Comment: Hola intenté pero aun me sigue mostrando el valor del title que tiene por defecto.

Comment: Aquí te dejo una prueba para que compruebes el funcionamiento https://jsfiddle.net/dx6km9y1/1/ @SimónPereiraVigouroux

Comment: ejecuté el ejemplo y sigue apareciendo "Horray" que es el title del input y lo que estoy intentando hacer es capturar el valor del input que en este caso es "DATO"

Comment: Igual no te entendi bien , pensé que querías cambiar el tooltip cada vez que ingresases un valor. SI solo quieres poner en el tooltip el valor que ya esta escrito en el input solo has de cambiar esto `$('#inputDatos').on('input',function(){` por esto `$('#inputDatos').on('onmouseover',function(){` . Aquí tienes el ejemplo https://jsfiddle.net/Lc9w3nxr/

Comment: Hola disculpa, pero parte debo quitar para que se muestre el valor del input por defecto? deberia quitar 'data-original-title' ? y dejar solo var campo = $('#inputDatos').attr(entrada);?

Comment: @SimónPereiraVigouroux no entiendo tu último comentario. Si lo que quieres enseñar es valor del input por defecto, tal cual te pase el ejemplo funciona. Lo único que cambia es el evento que dispara la ejecución del tooltip, que pasa de de ser **input** a **mouseover**

Comment: si ya lo vi lo que pasa es que recargo la página de stackoverflow y tu respuesta desaparece, pero solo donde indicas el codigo donde lo muestras. Seguramente son las cookies de mi navegador. Muchas gracias me sirvió la respuesta saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Algo así, al cambiar el texto cambiar el tooltip:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function textChange(e) {
    // cambiar valor del tooltip
}
</script>
...
<input type="text" id="inputDatos" value="DATO"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" onchange="textChange()">
...
```

Comment: El que vota en contra que explique **por qué** no está de acuerdo con ña solución y que proponga una mejor. Porque no veo nada desde el voto negativo.